# How to shift _token to the last of the url in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, csrf

Hello I want to shift the _token in the last of URL asshown below

What I am getting:

> example.com/search?_token=qkPc5aNyEp7tysbyQhZcnjHdP1wi9q&query=php

What I want:

> example.com/search?query=php&_token=qkPc5aNyEp7tysbyQhZcnjHdP1wi9q

My Form code Is like

```
<form action="search" method="GET">
                                    {!! csrf_field() !!}
                                <div class="main-search-input fl-wrap">
                                    <div class="main-search-input-item">
                                        <input type="text" name="query" value="" placeholder="Search snippets..." required>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <button class="main-search-button" type="submit">Search</button>
                                </div>

                                 </form>
```

Comment: The middleware that checks the CSRF token does not check it for GET requests, so you don't need the `_token` anyway as it is never used (you don't need the csrf field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the csrf field at the bottom of the form tho I think you don't need it.

Comment: Hey pagination not working now. can you please help me out!

Comment: Hello, what exactly is happening?

Comment: token not getting on page 2 and getting exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225259/discussion-between-upasana-chauhan-and-khaldoun-nd).